# How can I configure the MYSQL ODBC driver to work with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I've installed MYSQL server, running local on 127.0.0.1
(I've also tried this with MySQL server at a public IP with same results).

Here is how I'm configuring it:

Using MySQL Connector / ODBC (running localhost mysql server) using Visual Studio 2013 C#

I click Design tab of a webform.aspx page - and click and drag (from Toolbox->Data->GridView into the MainContent frame, and drop.

[image: VisualBasic2013 gridview]

I then click the [>] button
Under Choose Data Source, I choose to create a new data source.

[image: VisualBasic2013 Data Source Configuration Wizard]

Under Data Source Configuration Wizard, I choose SQL Database.

Next pops up a window, Configure Data Source - SqlDataSource1

[image: Configure Data Source]

I click New Connection

[image: Add Connection]

Microsoft ODBC Data Source (ODBC) is selected as Data source - I leave it (note:  here, I have tried changing this to MySql Data Source - but the connection fails).  so I use the ODBC option.

I click the () Use Connection string: and click [Build]

[image: Select Data Source]

A window pops up, and I select the Machine Data Source tab

I have already created a Data Source named test_localhost_mysql, I select it.

[image: Completed Data Source Information]

A window with MySQL Connector/ODBC connection parameters appears, with all of my connection data.  I click Test.

[image: ODBC connection test success]

success.

I click [OK]

Now, the Add Connection - Use connection string, is filled in, along with my login information.

I click Test Connection

[image: Add Connection Test Success]

Success.

I click [OK]

configuration wizard is now complete, and shows a string.

[image: Configure Data Source complete]

I click [NEXT]

[image: save connection]

I click [NEXT] without changing anything

Now is when it becomes interesting.  on this screen;

[image: data source configuration screen 3]

under Specify columns from a table or view - all my tables are in the drop down list.  Periodically, the columns will show here as well.  Currently they aren't -- I'm sure this is not random, although I'm not sure what I'm doing to cause it.

I click [Next] after selecting my table.

[image: data configuration test]

I click [TEST]

[image: data configuration test fails]

It fails.

I am sure it's something simple, but I promise I've been through everything I can think of, and can really use some help please.

Anyone that can guide me I would greatly appreciate it.

I anxiously await your genious :)  Thank you!

Comment: Which version of MySql connector are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Try to install with the instructions here. Report back if the issue persists.
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-odbc-connection.php

EDIT: You also might want to run through all of your SQL code. It clearly says that the SQL syntax is not correct.

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly what was happening.  Although, I did not write the code, it was generated incorrectly.  Thank you!

Comment: After studying the syntax error - as suggested, the query was including brackets.  I'm not sure why, I just assumed this was normal - although I had never used brackets inside my own queries, in this manner - and without an array.

So,

I simply remade the connection as shown above, but this time created my own query for select, update, insert, and delete.

I did this by clicking the [WHERE] button as shown above (prior to the last failed test) and went through each of the tabs.

Saved

Tested

Success!!